# Get source rows of LINQ query result?

Tags: vb.net, linq

In the following LINQ example, how can you get a list of index numbers from the original rows that the group is made up of? I would like to show the user where the data comes from.

```
    Dim inputDt As New DataTable
    inputDt.Columns.Add("Contractor")
    inputDt.Columns.Add("Job_Type")
    inputDt.Columns.Add("Cost")

    inputDt.Rows.Add({"John Smith", "Roofing", "2408.68"})
    inputDt.Rows.Add({"John Smith", "Electrical", "1123.08"})
    inputDt.Rows.Add({"John Smith", "Framing", "900.99"})
    inputDt.Rows.Add({"John Smith", "Electrical", "892.00"})

    Dim results = From rows In inputDt Where rows!Contractor <> ""
                  Group rows By rows!Job_Type
                    Into cost_total = Sum(CDec(rows!Cost))

    For Each r In results
        ' Show results.
        'r.Job_Type
        'r.cost_total

        ' Show line numbers of original rows... ?
    Next
```

For the result (Job_Type="Electrical", cost_total=2015.08), the original index numbers are 1 and 3.

Thanks

Comment: Create an anonymous type to store the info you care about.  Depending on how you want to store the indicies (CSV, collection), store that info.  `rows!Cost`  Rather than that,  you could use `row.Field(of Decimal)("cost")` and elide the old style VB6 functions/notations

Comment: @Plutonix I am not sure I understand. So how do you get to the underlying rows for each of the items In results? An example would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First and perhaps foremost, set **`Option Strict On`**.  This will not allow the old VB6 style `rows!Cost` type notation.  But this is for the better because that way always returns Object and the data rarely is.  This is no loss at all as NET has better ways to type and convert variables.

Second, and somewhat related, is that all your `DataTable` columns are text even though one is clearly decimal.  Next, your query relates to working with the data *in the table* but you want to also include a `DataRow` *property* which is a bit odd.  Better would be to add an `Id` or `Number` to the data to act as the identifier.  This will also help the results make sense if the View (order of rows) changes.

You did not clarify whether you wanted a CSV of indices (now IDs) or a collection of them.  A CSV of them seems simpler, so thats what this does.

The code also uses more idiomatic names and demonstrates casting data to the needed type using other extension methods.  It also uses the extension method approach.  First the DataTable with non-string Data Types specified:

```
Dim inputDt As New DataTable
inputDt.Columns.Add("ID", GetType(Int32))
inputDt.Columns.Add("Contractor")
inputDt.Columns.Add("JobType")
inputDt.Columns.Add("Cost", GetType(Decimal))

inputDt.Rows.Add({1, "John Smith", "Roofing", "2408.68"})
inputDt.Rows.Add({5, "John Smith", "Electrical", "1123.08"})
inputDt.Rows.Add({9, "John Smith", "Framing", "900.99"})
inputDt.Rows.Add({17, "John Smith", "Electrical", "892.00"})
```

then the query:

```
Dim summary = inputDt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(Function(g) g.Field(Of String)("JobType"),
                                             Function(k, v) New With {.Job = k,
                                                                    .Cost = v.Sum(Function(q) q.Field(Of Decimal)("Cost")), 
                                                                    .Indices = String.Join(",", inputDt.AsEnumerable().
                                                                                                  Where(Function(q) q.Field(Of String)("JobType") = k).
                                                                                                  Select(Function(j) j.Field(Of Int32)("Id")))
                                                                    }).
                                 OrderBy(Function(j) j.Cost).
                                 ToArray()

' Debug, test:
For Each item In summary
    Console.WriteLine("Job: {0}, Cost: {1}, Ids: {2}", item.Job, item.Cost, item.Indices)
Next
```

The excessive scroll is unfortunate but I left it to allow the clauses to align with what "level" they are acting at.  As you can see, a separate query is run on the `DataTable` to get the matching Indicies.

It is a little more typical to write such a thing as

```
Dim foo = Something.GroupBy(...).Select(...)
```

But you can skip the SELECT by using [this overload of GroupBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549393.aspx) as the above does:

```
Dim foo = Something.GroupBy(Function (g) ..., Function (k, v) ... )
```

Results:

> Job: Framing, Cost: 900.99, Ids: 9
>   Job: Electrical, Cost: 2015.08, Ids: 5,17
>   Job: Roofing, Cost: 2408.68, Ids: 1